# npm init not working on npm version greater than or equals to 8

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

npm init is not working in npm 8.3.1 can you help me with this? I have package.json.
Thank you

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: If you did all the steps after npm init (I see only package name step), it should work.
Please open the learningnode folder. I guess package.json was created.

Comment: The question title is misleading

Comment: There is no package. If I do npm init -y then it will create package.json with default entries. It won't let me enter it.

Comment: Share code instead of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I had npm 8.x and when I downgraded to 6.x it worked. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

**npm init** will create the **package.json** file with certain values like the package name, version, description, entry point etc. you can specify these values before creating package.json.

But to set all the values as default you can use the ***y*** flag to create package.json

> npm init -y

Comment: This was not working on npm 8. x and I downgraded it to 6.x. Finally, it worked. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @BishalTx Please avoid overwriting other answers to reply.